# {order_discount} Not Resetting

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, checkout, discounts

Currently I am using Expresso Store for my checkout module using EE2. When I add a product - which got a 50% discount - to the cart, the `{order_discount}` tag displays half the price of the product which is correct.

However, when I remove the product from the cart and remove the sale from that product via the backend and re-add the product (which previously had the sale), the `{order_discount}` still displays half the price as this discount is already recorded in the database. Should the removal of the product not reset/retract the discount from the `{order_discount}` tag or database? Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have cleared your cart to reset the session which should then reset the `{order_discount}` tag

Comment: Would I also have to do this if removing only one product?